# Why is my first activity don't show up?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I make a splashscreen, but my splashscreen don't show up. After 4 seconds the second splashscreen will show up. 
I want show up my splashscreen for 4 seconds.
This is my code:

```
package com.geven.headsoccer.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class SplashScreen extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.geven.headsoccer.LIBGDX_GAME"));
        }



    }
```

Comment: Try moving `startActivity(new Intent("com.geven.headsoccer.LIBGDX_GAME"));` to the try block after thread.sleep() and see if the second activity is showing..please remember to remove the finally block...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show your SplashScreen for 4 seconds, why don't you use Handler?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {                
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a handler.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            // Using handler with postDelayed called runnable run method

            @Override
            public void run() {
                                startActivity(new Intent("com.geven.headsoccer.LIBGDX_GAME"));

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, 4*1000); // wait for 5 seconds
```